# Add multiple list items in the same column in vertical position | MVC HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a way to add list items to the same column, not separate columns. However I am not sure how to make it appear in vertical line instead of horizontal.

The way I have it now is:

```
  @foreach (var item in result.NumberList)
  {
      <td class="col">@item</td>
  }
```

So to visualize it, this is how it looks:

**Column**

number number2 number3

And I want it to look like that:

**Column**

number

number2 ----All the numbers should appear vertically in the same row.

number3

**Thanks In Advance**

Comment: You need to add rows inside your loop, for example `<tr><td class="col">@item</td></tr>`.

Comment: @morgh generate a string out of your list and add as a single value to cell you need.

Comment: but I want to add multiple values to a single cell

Answer (score 0):

You should do :

```
@foreach (var item in result.NumberList)
{
   <tr>
     <td class="col">@item</td>
   </tr>
}
```

tr elements create a new table row.

You should search for [HTML tables](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

Comment: This solution displays list items in separate rows. I want to make sure that list items are displayed in the same row and one column. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @morgh Sounds like you just need to open the td outside the loop and include a `<br/>` between each item within the loop.

Comment: @morgh Also, no one would know this requirement from the example you gave.  Usually when trying to solve complex Razor problems, I first mockup the HTML I want to produce, then work backwards from there.

Comment: @AaronLS : by adding <br> it adds big space in horizontal direction, nothing appear vertically.

Comment: @morgh Mockup the HTML that produces the appearance you desire, update your question, and then we can propose the Razor syntax that produces that HTML. We can make a hundred guesses at HTML and each time you might find problems with the appearance you don't like.

Comment: how many items do you have? What if you have more than can fit in a column without them being illegible?